# MySQL cursor's FETCH not working for time datatype

Tags: mysql, database, cursor

MySQL cursor's FETCH not working for time datatype

Given cursor related code

```
declare Normaltimeopen time;
declare cursorName cursor for select statement;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET flag = 1;
open cursorName;
Fetch cursorName into Normaltimeopen ;
IF flag = 1 THEN
    CLOSE cursorName ;        
END IF;
close cursorName;
```

So, Normaltimeopen variable gets set to '00:00:00' but table contains value '16:00:00'.
I debugged with "debugger for mysql" but not getting any clue.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the problem, test code works as expected:

```sql
/*Table structure for table `table1` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `tablenormaltimeopen` TIME DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/*Data for the table `table1` */

INSERT  INTO `table1`(`tablenormaltimeopen`) VALUES ('16:00:00');

/* Procedure structure for procedure `sp_test` */

/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `sp_test` */;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `flag` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `Normaltimeopen` TIME;
    DECLARE `cursorName` CURSOR FOR
    SELECT `tablenormaltimeopen` FROM `table1`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `flag` := 1;
    OPEN `cursorName`;
    FETCH `cursorName` INTO `Normaltimeopen`;
    IF NOT `flag` THEN
        SELECT `Normaltimeopen`;
    END IF;
    CLOSE `cursorName`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be924/1)</kbd>